# Firing event in list in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have implemented a list in blackberry. How do I fire event 'on click' of the list?

Answer (score 1):

The `ListField` has a protected method that you can overwrite,

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time).
```

Within the method `navigationClick` method you can get the selected list item (row) with the method getSelectedIndex().

So you'll have something such as:

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
int sectionIndex = getSelectedIndex();
```